# openlayers 3 (or oracle) convert 2d to 3d

Tags: openlayers, oracle-spatial

We have an existing oracle gis which is being reworked. We're not really touching the oracle stored procedures or tables.
In the table, the sdo_geometry appears to be a 3D line, with 0 as the z value. I'm not entirely sure why it was written this way, I wasn't there when it was written.  However, when this data gets brought into an openlayers vector layer and I observer the feature geometry, there is no Z value, so somehow it's being converted from 3D to 2D.
In my new code I'm actually sending the data to oracle as a WKT, and then converting it to an sdo_geometry in an oracle helper function which passes the data to the other procedure which takes an sdo_geometry (I couldn't find a way to convert to sdo_geometry format in c# or javascript). So the linestring is being sent as 2D which the database expects 3D so therein lies my problem. I think I can get around this on a few ways, but I don't know how to do any of them. I could...

A. Force my vector layer in openlayers to be 3D. with z value of 0.

B. use some (unknown to me) openlayers function to return a 3D version of the geometry (or WKT) given a 2D, with Z set to 0.

C. use Oracle (in my helper function) to make the sdo_geometry 3D (a different constuctor maybe?) currently using sdo_geometry(wkt_in,srid) srid is 8307 if that matters.

D. Write my own function in javascript or C# which will just parse the WKT and add a 0 to each coordinate set. I don't have a problem doing this, but would rather use existing functions if they're available.

E. something else I haven't thought of :)

Answer (score 1):

What version of Oracle database do you use ?

My recommended approach is definitely to turn the shapes in the database into 2D shapes by removing the 0 Z values. This is easily done using the SDO_CS.MAKE_2D() function (see https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_cs_ref.htm#SPATL1068)

3D shapes with all Z set to 0 are generally uploaded from CAD systems. But the Z are just fillers and should not be there in the first place. Having 3D shapes with Z to 0 was fine with old versions (Oracle 10g and before) where those Z are ignored. But on current supported versions (11g and later), the Z are really interpreted as such.

So a line with Z set to 0 is considered to be at an elevation of 0, and all queries and processing use that information. For example another line with explicit Z will not be considered as intersecting that line at elevation 0 - but it did with the older Oracle 10g versions.

Using Oracle geometries in Java is achieved using the Oracle Spatial Java API. Check out the oracle.spatial.geometry package at https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPAJV/toc.htm

If you insist on keeping the shapes as is, then you can use option C: just use the SDO_CS.MAKE_3D() function (see https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SPATL/sdo_cs_ref.htm#SPATL1069)
It lets you turn a 2D shape (without Z) into a 3D shape with all Z set to a fixed value, for example:

```
sdo_cs.make_3d(sdo_geometry(wkt_in,srid),0)
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
We're using Oracle 11g (11.203 I've ben told).  The database is an existing live db which was written using a 3D geometry.  My boss thinks it was set up that way because of a port from ArcGIS(I have no personal knowledge about this). But we're unable to change this.
I'm able to send the wkt to an oracle helper function which I wrote which will convert it to sdo_geometry, and that works just fine for 2D but sdo_util's from_wktgeometry does not support 3D. Converting the WKT to 3D was fairly easy, I was able to parse it myself.
And we're using C#, not java.

Comment: I found that sdo_util's from_gmlgeometry does in fact support conversion to a 3D sdo_geometry from a 3D gml. And, Openlayers has a function to return the gml format for the geometry of the selected feature.  I will need to parse and tweak the gml a bit to force it to 3D from 2D, but I think this route will work. Thanks again for your input.
Oh and I see above where I made a typo to make you think java was an option, I meant javascript, not java. Although the legacy system was total java. We're going to mvc C# and HTML5.